# No source code is available for type <type> did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: maven, gwt, gwt-maven-archetypes

I am trying to split my project into 4 Java modules:

```
web-client
web-client-admin
web-client-landing
web-client-core
```

The module `web-client` is the one that puts all pieces together, so the dependency tree would look something like this:

```
                <-- web-client-admin <----
               /                          \ 
web-client <---                            <---- web-client-core
               \                          /
                <-- web-client-landing <--
```

In my `module.gwt.xml` I am having:

```xml
<inherits name="com.mz.client.application.landing" />
<inherits name="com.mz.client.application.admin" />
<inherits name="com.mz.client.application.core" />
```

and the java modules are in the `pom.xml` of the `web-client` module:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mz</groupId>
        <artifactId>mz-web-client-admintool</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mz</groupId>
        <artifactId>mz-web-client-landing</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I am getting:

```
[INFO]       Compiling module com.mz.client.ClientEntryPoint
[INFO]          Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.mz.client.application.ApplicationBootstrapper'
[INFO]             [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/E:/java/mz/mz-server/mz-web-client/src/main/java/com/mz/client/application/ApplicationBootstrapper.java'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 144: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.network.ParallelRequest.ParallelCallback; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 77: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.dao.app.ApplicationData; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 103: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.network.XsrfRequest<S,R>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 144: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.dao.shop.ShopAdmin; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 49: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.LogMessageFormatter; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.mz.client.application.ApplicationModule'
[INFO]             [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/E:/java/mz/mz-server/mz-web-client/src/main/java/com/mz/client/application/ApplicationModule.java'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 18: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.landing.LandingModule; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 20: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.admin.AdminToolModule; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.mz.client.application.login.LoginPresenter'
[INFO]             [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/E:/java/mz/mz-server/mz-web-client/src/main/java/com/mz/client/application/login/LoginPresenter.java'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 124: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.event.AdminLoginEvent; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 75: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.network.Request<R>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 112: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.dao.shop.ShopAdmin; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 112: No source code is available for type com.mz.client.application.core.network.ParallelRequest.ParallelCallback; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

I don't see what I am missing here..

Comment: it looks like the web-client-coe module is not in the class path. Is it another jar that have to be added as  dependency in the pom?

Comment: @ElHoss `web-client-core` is added as dependency in `web-client-admin` and `web-client-landing`.. But the logging shows that it can't find the sources of `landing` and `admin` as well.. :/

Comment: Did you tell maven to export also the sources?

Comment: @ElHoss Hm, after you mentioned this I used the [maven-source-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html) to make sure the sources are packed - but I'm still getting this error .. this is so annoying ..

Comment: Do you have any resources located under resources, that should be exported?

Comment: But looking at the errpr message, I would expect, that the sources files are not exported ...

Comment: @ElHoss Yeah, I used the `resources` plugin as Thomas suggested. I don't understand why it didn't work with the maven-source-plugin but I'm glad it finally compiles :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to include source files as resources into your modules, or add dependencies to the sources artifacts in addition to the jar ones.

Given that these are all client modules, I'd rather include the sources into the JARs.

You can simply declare `src/main/java` as an additional `<resource>`, or you can use a gwt-maven-plugin (maybe have a look at https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/ `gwt-lib` packaging; disclaimer: I'm the author)